# Is the statement of this lemma wrong (Jordan decomposition)?

Tags: measure-theory, logic

In the context of Hahn decomposition theorem, given a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{F})$ and a signed measure $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we define
$$\varphi^{+}(A):=\underset{A\supset Y\in\mathcal{F}}{\sup}\varphi(Y)\geqslant0.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
Then $\varphi^{+}$ will be used in the Jordan-Hahn theorem for the Jordan decomposition. It is useful that $\varphi^{+}(A)<\infty$. One way is a reductio ad absurdum, but first I needed the following lemma:

> Let $A\in\mathcal{F}$. If $\varphi^{+}(A)=+\infty$, then $\exists S\in\mathcal{F}, S\subset A$ such that
>
> - $\varphi(S)>1$
> - $|\varphi(A\setminus S)|>1$
> - **Either** $\varphi^{+}(S)=+\infty$ **or** $\varphi^{+}(A\setminus S)=+\infty$

I suspect that the third point should only be an *inclusive* disjunction, not exclusive. The proof I was given didn't mention it. Since it's brief, here it is. Let $Y\in\mathcal{F}, Y\subset A$. Using a useful decomposition of $Y$ and finite additivity
$$\varphi(Y)=\varphi(Y\cap S)+\varphi(Y\setminus S)\leqslant\varphi^{+}(S)+\varphi^{+}(A\setminus S).$$
Having used the definition of supremum in the last inequality. Now taking the supremum of the $\text{LHS}$, we find using \eqref{1}
$$\varphi^{+}(A)\leqslant\varphi^{+}(S)+\varphi^{+}(A\setminus S).$$
and we conclude that if both summands in the $\text{RHS}$ are finite, we find an absurdum, $\varphi^{+}(A)=+\infty$ by hypothesis.
Alright so as you can see it doesn't mention the case where they're both infinite. Is there something I can't see or just a mistake in the statement of the lemma?

Comment: I don't take "either... or..." to be exclusive to begin with. The assumption that "or" is inclusive is so common that I'd specifically write "but not both" if I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: @MishaLavrov That strikes me as a surprise: I know that "or" alone may also be exclusive but I though that "either...or" made exclusiveness clear, at least in math context. Now, English is not my first language and this was a translation of the Italian "o...o" which I've always considerer as exclusive. So would you conclude that in this case we have inclusive disjunction?

Comment: If you take a look at the [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure#Definition), it says that "One consequence is that an extended signed measure can take $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ as a value, but not both." This seems to indicate that exclusive-or was intended.